# save image automatically (coding) to resources.resx in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I create and automatically save a picture to resources.resx in vb.net?
I tried but it only saves to the resources folder. What I want is to automatically save it to the resources inside the vb. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible, but why don't you just save it to a custom folder? Maybe even in your application folder (Debug) so that you only have to access it with it's name.

I suggest you save it in a folder that you make in your debug folder, maybe call it Images. Then just save the image to the folder and you're done. After this you will always be able to access this image with dim ImagePath as String = "Images/yourpicture.jpg"

I assume you know how to save an image?

```
Image.Save(ImagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```